# Low Pressure In House (Rainwater capture system)

Tags: plumbing

Water pressure is low in entire house. We're on a rainwater capture system. We've been on this system for nearly 7 years, never had this issue.

We have large water tanks that pull in from a pump into a pressure tank. It then goes into a debris filter, 3 stage RO system, then to water heater and to house. It's not a fancy set up by any means but it's worked well.

The water will come on strong and slowly fade out, sometimes to nothing. I replaced the RO filter 4 days ago and it helped temporarily. I opened them again today and replaced the first stage as it was already pretty dark. It worked well again for a little while then started having same problem.

Pressure tank pressure (top) was at 34 psi when I checked it, so it seems to have pressure. Interestingly when I open the water heater pressure valve, it comes out very slowly.

I suspect some kind of clog as we had absolutely crazy oak pollen to the point our water is yellow. I just don't know how to diagnose it if it is!

Comment: If you open the connection *before* the heater, does water keep up pressure? If so, then the fault is **inside** the heater, perhaps debris blocking the outlet. The heater could be flushed, or back-flushed, to fix that.

Comment: Have you serviced the "debris filter"?

Comment: We had a rainwater / reservoir system and used 3 sandfilters to trap most of the pollutants. Each sand filter held about 3 cubic metres of sand. 2 in use at any time to get the flow rate needed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik would that cause low pressure for cold water too?

Comment: @TexasGuy, no, but the system you described seemed to have all water going into the heater.

Answer (score 1):

I had rain capture system in Cali.

4 barrels and suction pump

All the time I had mold/mildew problems (dark green water), probably contaminated by roof.

My advice check for mold/mildew clogging.

The pressure was dropping and the pump had problem maintaining the flow and pressure.

The only solution that worked for me is to use bleach, that would obviously kill the purpose of using the water for drinking or even watering.

I switched to using rain inlet filters that helped some.

Once in a while I cleaned the system with vinegar that helped some but again I had to flush it to get rid of the vinegar.

Comment: If you use the right amount of bleach, not so much of a problem, really: https://www.epa.gov/ground-water-and-drinking-water/emergency-disinfection-drinking-water

Comment: Where was your clog happening?

Comment: once it was contaminated it spread everywhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems the second stage filter was where the pressure really fell off. It was very clogged up, even with a new filter. I removed it, put the cover back on and the pressure was back to normal.

I think the oak pollen is just overloading the filter system.